# Spinner Adding/Getting Value in Fragment

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

What is the Best way to Add and Get Value in Spinner in Fragment?

**XML**

```
 <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Status"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
```

**Java**

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   
    final View root= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container, false);
    Spinner status = root.findViewById(R.id.Status);  
    return root;`
```

`

**Adding Data**

```
  String[] role = new String[] {"Faculty","Student"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,role);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    status.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Getting Data**

```
 String state = status.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `OnItemSelectedListener`

```
spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

        override fun onItemSelected(adapterView: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
        }

        override fun onNothingSelected(adapterView: AdapterView<*>?) {
        }

    }
```